# What is the working principle of a bamboo cannon in terms of energy physics?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, experimental-physics, applied-physics

[image: The Bamboo Cannon]

A typical bamboo cannon consists of a large bamboo node or tube containing some water to which a little calcium carbide (or kerosene) is added. Bamboo cannon's popular in Malaysia, Indonesia, and Philippines. In Indonesia bamboo cannon is traditional game played by children. It was very popular since 1990s. Nowadays, it's still played by children in rural areas, where the material (bamboo) is widely available.

Usually, a match is inserted into the bamboo which is already filled with water + fuel, then the bamboo will make an explosive sound like a cannon, and can even "release" a fire. I am curious about the question: "are there any physics concepts/principle (e.g. energy) in the game (bamboo cannon)?". I've tried to search for local journal articles to find the answer, but nothing explains about it.

Does any of you know the answer? Can you share it here?

(Write down the reference source, if any. Another note: identifying the physics aspect in the bamboo cannon is one of my Energy Physics Course assignments.)

Comment: What is a physical aspect of energy?

Answer (score 1):

These have been popular in the USA for decades. My college roommate built one using cut-up beer cans in 1971, that ran on cigarette lighter fluid. It was called a *beer can cannon* and if it was used to shoot potatoes (a common projectile) it was a *potato cannon*.

You can easily model such a cannon as an internal combustion engine with a compression ratio of 1:1 and no piston.

The thermodynamic cycle upon which it works is called the *Lenoir cycle* and a complete description of it can be found on wikipedia.